# optimization with python cvxopt

Tags: python, optimization, cvxopt

I am trying to minimize the [portfolio variance](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/071515/how-can-i-measure-portfolio-variance.asp) using Python's cvxopt. However, after lots of trying, it doesn't seem to work. The function and my code and  the error are pasted below. Thanks for helping!

### the minimize problem

objective function: min x.dot(sigma_mv).dot(x.T)

the constraint condition is all x>=0, sum(X) = 1

sigma_mv is the covariance matrix of 800*800, dim = 800

### code

```
dim = sigma_mv.shape[0]
P = 2*sigma_mv   
q = np.matrix([0.0])
G = -1*np.identity(dim)
h = np.matrix(np.zeros((dim,1)))

sol = solvers.qp(P,q,G,h)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-47-a077fa141ad2>", line 6, in <module>
    sol = solvers.qp(P,q)   

  File "D:\spyder\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\coneprog.py", line 4470, in qp
    return coneqp(P, q, G, h, None, A,  b, initvals, kktsolver = kktsolver, options = options)

  File "D:\spyder\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\coneprog.py", line 1822, in coneqp
    raise ValueError("use of function valued P, G, A requires a "\

ValueError: use of function valued P, G, A requires a user-provided kktsolver
```

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Comment: The error tells you that cvxopt is not able to see you input as matrices. It thinks some of these are functions. As your code is incomplete (no def of sigma_mv; your description does not help here) it's hard to reason about. So either, sigma_mv is broken, or, and i'm too lazy to check: does cvxopt really can use numpy.matrices? cvxopt usually has it's own matrix-format (there are even numpy -> cvxopt transformation examples somewhere in the docs).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it really solves the problem. The P Q G H is not the correct matrix form defined in the cvxopt. the correct form is as following:    from cvxopt import solvers, matrix                                                   P = 2*matrix(mat)  
    q = matrix([0.0]*dim)
    G = -1*matrix(np.identity(dim))
    h = matrix(np.zeros((dim,1)))

Comment: also `np.array(1.0) * matrix(G)` is not a matrix

Comment: cvxopt is a great solver. We just need to take care that our P matrix is positive definite or any other important considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You have both equality and inequality constraints so you need to provide all the arguments to the built-in qp solver
Gx <=h
Ax=b

Here x>=0 can be written as -x<=0 So, G matrix  will look like -1*(Identity matrix)
 and h will a 0 vector
Similarly, your A will be an Identity matrix and b will be a unity vector(all elements =1)

Finally, solve expression should look like :

```
sol=solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)
```